# React purpose of custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out what is the purpose of introducing something called `custom hooks` when its just a function.  If I take the following example https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/react-custom-hooks-a-simple-intuition-if-you-still-cant-hit-it-off-8d27fa4ba10, if I don't use the `use` prefix for the hook, it all still works fine.  With the introduction of this terminology called `custom hooks` I'm not sure whats the purpose of it, or should I just go on using standard functions.

What is the main advantage I get when using the `use` prefix for a `custom hook` or function apart from some simple linting features?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the main advantage I get when using the use prefix for a
> custom hook or function apart from some simple linting features?

Reasons are stated in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html):

> Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”? Please do. This
> convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
> automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
> couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
> it.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing. There is no difference between them. `useFoo` function is just a function. In source code, it was not dealt with specially. It is just little bit complicated, but no difference between regular functions.

`use` prefix is just a term, or just culture, whether you obey it is entrusted to you. Of course, obeying the culture bring us good result. But this and that have no connection. Custom hooks are just functions.

Answer (score -1):

In very basic words: You can reuse stateful logic between components, witch is not possible with regular functions. I would suggest that you read the documentation, because ReactJS has a pretty good one :)
Stay safe

Comment: React  is pretty good, but what you say is ambiguous, so down voted.